# How does the C# conditional operator ? evaluate when used in pairs

Tags: c#, operators, conditional-statements

I'm trying to figure out what this code does in C# I'm not that familiar with the ? operator and this usage is confusing me. 
I know that if I do something like this.

```
Result = ans > 0 ? string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(line[0]) : "";
```

It boils down to this:

```
if(ans > 0)
    Result = string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(line[0]);
else 
    Result = "";
```

However I don't understand what happens when the line is like this instead:

```
Result = ans > 0 
       ? string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(line[0]) 
       ? ""
       : line[0].Trim().ToUpper() 
       : "";
```

When it is written this way does it just pair the ? and with the first : it comes to? That doesn't really make sense because Result can only have one value. Hopefully this makes sense I tried to condense the code down to just the problem I am having so that it is easy to understand. Let me know if I'm not clear enough.

Comment: From left to right, from top to down.

Comment: This won't compile since `value++` is not a boolean.

Comment: It looks like it won't even compile. Maybe you condensed wrong or tagged with the wrong language. Test your code before posting.

Comment: Sorry I modified the second part so that it compiles now. The first example explanation just regard it as sudo code.

Comment: Don't write code like this because it makes it hard to read and other developers have to come here to ask how it works.  :-)

Comment: @JasonNesbitt, I was going to comment that the question was academic because it would never clear code review.

Comment: @JasonNesbitt, Sorry is that better? I was trying to be extra explicit with my question and I goofed up.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no ambiguity in parsing the expression of the form `a ? b ? c : d : e`: the only way to parse it is

```
a ? (b ? c : d) : e
```

A more interesting parse would be when a conditional expression is used as the last operand, not the middle. [Microsoft documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ty67wk28.aspx) provides the answer to this:

> The conditional operator is right-associative.
>   The expression `a ? b : c ? d : e` is evaluated as `a ? b : (c ? d : e)`, not as `(a ? b : c) ? d : e`.

However, it is a good idea to at least parenthesize expressions like that, because some readers of your code would need to consult a language reference in order to understand a potentially simple piece of logic.

Comment: So, what does `value ++  ? "": line[0]` evaluate to?

Comment: @HenkHolterman OP has removed the part that didn't compile from his question.

Comment: And `a ? b ? c : d : e` is `a ? (b ? c : d) : e`

Comment: @juharr You're right, OP's expression is unambiguous, because the conditional is in the middle position. Thanks!

Comment: Just to clarify I didn't write the code this way someone else did. I'm just trying to figure out what it means. So basically what I've gotten out of this is that when the ? operator is used again right after the first ? instead of the : it just means that we are doing another if statement and the following : is paired with that and the last : pairs to the original conditional. Correct?

Comment: @Macuserman17 Yes, this is correct when the nested conditional is in the last position. When it's in the middle position, like in your code, there is only one way to parse the expression, i.e. take the expression between the question marks as the second condition, and pair it up with the two expressions that follow.

Answer (score 3):

From your post,

```
Result = ans > 0 
   ? string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(line[0]) 
   ? ""
   : line[0].Trim().ToUpper() 
   : "";
```

is equivalent to

```
if( ans > 0 )
{
    if( string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(line[0]) )
    {
         Result = "";
    }
    else
    {
         Result = line[0].Trim().ToUpper();
    }
}
else
{
     Result = "";
}
```